# PostgresSql max dates last 30 dates

Tags: max

In my dataset I have a list dates

How do I tag the latest 30 dates as "max"?

Col A: Dates
Col B: Values
Col C: Tag as "Max" or "NA"

Answer (score 1):

I am making the assumptions that you don't know how recent to the current date the set will be or if it contains sparse dates. I don't have a running Postgres instance at the moment but this should be extremely close.

```
SELECT
        t.ColA
        , t.ColB
        , CASE WHEN t2.ColA IS NOT NULL THEN 'Max' ELSE 'NA' END AS ColC
FROM TableName t
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT inner_t.ColA
                 FROM TableName inner_t
                 ORDER BY 1 DESC
                 LIMIT 30) t2
ON t.ColA = t2.ColA
```